# Simple HTTP Proxy for multiple client authentication

Tags: ssl, http-proxy

I have a web application running that takes incoming connections from various clients. Now I need to perform client authentication for each incoming connection.

A separate application running on the same server as the web app, generates automatically certificates (crt+key) and distributes the crt+key to the single clients. The certificate should be used on the server side for the client authentication.

Is there an easy way to setup a simple HTTP proxy in front of the web app to perform this client authentication and if successful, forward the request to the web app?
Note that I must be able to specify a directory of certificates that should be used for verification not just one certificate only, since each client has their own!